# How to unit test urls.py when included by project?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, tdd

How can I run unit tests to validate that a certain URL calls a particular function?

I want to do something like this:

```
class HomePageTest(TestCase):

  def test_root_url_resolves_to_list_view(self):
    found = resolve('/testme/')
    self.assertEqual(found.func.func_name, ListView.__name__)
    #self.assertEqual(found.func, ListView.as_view())
```

But lets imagine the apps urls.py is included in the projects urls.py under something like:

```
url(r'^submodule/$', include('fhqna.urls')),
```

How can I write the test included in the app so it checks the url "/testme/" indepent of how it is included? ("/submodule/testme/" in this example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure [urls for test case](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/tools/#urlconf-configuration)

```
class HomePageTest(TestCase):

    urls = 'fhqna.urls'

    def test_root_url_resolves_to_list_view(self):
        found = resolve('/testme/')
        self.assertEqual(found.func.func_name, ListView.__name__)
```

Or give a name to your url and resolve it by this name regardless of actual url is used. In this case you don't need to configure urls for TestCase.